# Working with SharpUSBLib

Tags: c#, .net, usb

i'd like to connect my Android smartphone from an .NET application. Anyway, [**SharpUSBLib**](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpusblib/) looks like it can do this.

Does anyone know so good tutorials about working with SharpUSBLib? I did't find any and don't know how to use it.

Tanks!

Comment: Did you download the samples and documentation as well?

Comment: Which documentation? There is only one sample C# file included. But don't know how to get it working. Can't find any documentation on the official site.

Comment: That looks quite old... 2004...